# Best way to align a responsive SVG vertically after page width gets too narrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have two SVGs side by side on a page. I want one to remain fixed size, but the other can scale as necessary. I have this working.

However, once the browser window is narrow enough, I want the two SVGs to align vertically instead. This is where I am stuck. I think I can potentially add/remove a class based on the window size and have corresponding css to adjust the layout but my attempts at that have failed so far.

Here is a JS fiddle demonstrating where I have gotten. 
[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/r58ecvow/9/)

```js
$(function() {

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var chart = $("#rightEl");
    var container = chart.parent();
    var targetWidth = container.width();
    chart.attr("width", targetWidth > 300 ? 300 : targetWidth)
      .attr("height", targetWidth > 300 ? 300 : targetWidth)
    //at some point when targetWidth < "n" i want to align
    //vertically
  }).trigger("resize");
})
```

```css
#leftEl {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

#right-wrapper {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
  <svg id="leftEl" width="300" height="300" class="svg-container">
      <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="150" class="r" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></circle>
    </svg>
  <div id="right-wrapper" width="300" height="300">
    <svg id="rightEl" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="300" height="300">
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="150" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></circle>
      </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain javascript version of checking window size. This is set to trigger the if statement when the window width is less than 900 px, but you can obviously set it however you want.

`width` is declared as a this-scope-only variable here with `let`, so you won't be able to access the `width` variable outside of this function.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function( event ){

  // variable that tracks page width
  let width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

if (width < 900) {

    yourVariableNameHere.classList.remove('classNameToRemove');

}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add media query's and changes the css

https://jsfiddle.net/h93cqoaw/

```css
#leftEl {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

#right-wrapper {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:650px){
  #leftEl {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  }
  #right-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <svg id="leftEl" width="300" height="300" class="svg-container">
      <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="150" class="r" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></circle>
    </svg>
    <div id="right-wrapper" width="300" height="300">
      <svg id="rightEl" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="300" height="300">
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="150" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```